# knitr: child document in different directory

Tags: r, sweave, knitr

I can use the following code for child document if it is in the same directory.

```
<<child-demo, child=knitr-input-child.Rnw, eval=TRUE>>=
@
```

I wonder how to use child document if it is not in the same directory of master document. Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Comment: I assume you've tried the obvious (but quite possibly not-working) `child=inputdir/input-child.Rnw`?

Comment: the easier way to use the `child` feature is to just use `\Sexpr{knit_child('inputdir/input-child.Rnw')}

Comment: you can update from github: https://github.com/yihui/knitr it writes tex files in correct places, but I still need to think about the path of plot files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be considered as a bug. Now I have fixed it on [GitHub](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#readme). Note, however, you need to `setwd()` to the directory of your master document before using `knit()`, otherwise `knit()` may not be able to find a child `inputdir/child.Rnw`. Please see if the development version works for you. Thanks!

Comment: Now it works. Thanks @Yihui for your help and such a nice package.

Comment: No problem, and just FYI, v0.2 is on CRAN now: http://cran.r-project.org/package=knitr