# knitr: source() a file in a child document --- working directory changed

Tags: r, knitr, children

I ran into an unexpected problem trying to source a file containing some functions in a child document of a knitr .Rnw file.  My directory structure is

```
CARME2015.Rnw  -- main file
  /frames
  /examples
  /fig
...
```

The main file contains this chunk:

```
<<odds, child="frames/odds.Rnw">>=
@
```

In a child file, ./frames/odds.Rnw, I had the following chunk:

```
<<hv-setup, include=FALSE >>=
source("examples/odds.R")
@
```

Running knitr under RStudio gave this error:

```
> knit2pdf("CARME2015.Rnw", quiet = TRUE)
processing file: ./frames/intro.Rnw
processing file: ./frames/ucb-ex.Rnw
processing file: ./frames/odds.Rnw
Quitting from lines 2-9 (./frames/odds.Rnw) 
Quitting from lines 78-93 (./frames/odds.Rnw) 
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
```

I finally realized that the `child=` chunk option must reset the current working directory to that containing the child file, so the following **did work** to include my R file:

```
<<hv-setup, include=FALSE >>=
source("../examples/odds.R")
@
```

I wonder if this should be considered a bug or a 'feature'?  In LaTeX, paths to included files are always considered relative to the document root directory,  e.g.,

```
\includegraphics{fig/myfig}
```

will work anywhere within the document file structure.

(Related topic: [knitr: child document in different directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041589/knitr-child-document-in-different-directory))

Answer (score 2):

Whether you consider it a bug or a feature is up to you, but this behaviour is documented in `?knit`:

> The working directory when evaluating R code chunks is the directory of the input document by default […].

As child documents are just (RNW) "documents included in documents" it's quite natural that child documents get their own working directory.

The comparison to LaTeX is not valid, as there you `input` only fragments of a document, not a self-contained document. (Recall: The child document contains *chunks* not just the *content of one chunk*, that's what I mean by "self-contained" here.)

That said, this is how you can avoid problems that might occur due to the standard behaviour: In the main file, set [`root.dir`](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/#package-options) to the current working directory.

`main.Rnw`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<>>=
library(knitr)
opts_knit$set(root.dir = getwd())

print(getwd())
@

<<child = "sub/child.Rnw">>=
@

\end{document}
```

`sub/child.Rnw`:

```
<<>>=
print(getwd())
@
```

This prints the same directory twice. If you skip the `opts_knit`, the child document is evaluated with the working directory set to `sub`.